# UItableView one cell repeats 13 times in each section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing an iOS app using objective-c. I'm having custom cell in `UITableview`. the section and rows in section count is unknown every time ,
the problem I'm facing is each row in one section repeats 13 times then same with next section my code for tableview is

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
ProductCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ProductCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
                NSDate *dateRepresentingThisDay = [self.sorteddays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                eventsOnThisDay = [self.sections objectForKey:dateRepresentingThisDay];


                double interval =[[eventsOnThisDay objectAtIndex:indexOfDateWithTime] doubleValue];
                NSDate *celldate=[[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a"];
                cell.TitleLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [eventsOnThisDay objectAtIndex:indexOfTitle]];
                cell.DateTimeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:celldate]];
                cell.NameLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [eventsOnThisDay objectAtIndex:indexOfName]];
                cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

      return cell;
```

self.section is `NSDictionary` with date key for particular product array/arrays on that day and i am getting this kind of result

[image]

Comment: cell = [[ProductCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil]; change the reuse identifier = nill

Comment: show your other tableview delegate methods

Comment: You're not using `indexPath.row` anywhere, only the section. How are you expecting to return different info for each row?

Comment: hi @JamesP thanks for help , now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the data for display for every row is based on  `dateRepresentingThisDay`，but the value of it, is based on section. Check your code:

```
NSDate *dateRepresentingThisDay = [self.sorteddays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

So, in the same section, for all cell's the data is the same!